# Is there a driver for FX CP215 w colour laser printer?

Tags: drivers, printing

The printer is connected via ethernet and has an IP address;  under Ubuntu 15.04 Add a Printer finds and recommends a few drivers but none of them actually work.  One of them actually starts the rollers turning but nothing else happens.